# "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" when defining Glop Solver constraints?

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, maximize

I'm very new to Python so forgive me if this is a silly question - but I've been trying to figure out why I'm getting this error every time I try to define my constraints in an optimization problem I'm working on.

Below is my code:

```
# input parameters
product = ['Chairs', 'Desks', 'Tables']               # list of product names
department = ['Fabrication', 'Assembly', 'Shipping']  # list of constraint names
profit = [15.00, 24.00, 18.00]                        # list of product profit coefficients
max_sales = [360, 300, 100]                           # list of maximum sales for each product
hours_req = [[4, 6, 2], [3, 5, 7], [3, 2, 4]]         # two dimensional list of hour constraint coefficients
                                                      # each sublist corresponds to a constraint
hours_avl = [1850, 2400, 1500]                        # list of hours available for each department

# initialize LP model object
mymodel = glp.Solver('Lexington', glp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)

# define decision variables
dvar = list(range(len(product)))         # create a list to store one variable for each product
for i in range(len(product)):            # loop to create a variable for each product
    dvar[i] = mymodel.NumVar(0, mymodel.infinity(), product[i])
                                         # arguments: (lower bound, upper bound, name)

# define objective function
TotProfit = mymodel.Objective()          # create objective function object
TotProfit.SetMaximization()              # set direction of optimization
for i in range(len(product)):      # loop to set the objective coefficient for each product variable
    TotProfit.SetCoefficient(dvar[i], profit[i])
                                         # arguments: (variable, coefficient)

# define constraints
hours_constr = list(range(len(department)))
for h in range(len(department)):
    constr[h] = mymodel.Constraint(0, hours_avl[h])
    for f in range(len(product)):
        constr[h].SetCoefficient(dvar[f], hours_req[h][f])
    for a in range(len(product)):
        constr[h].SetCoefficient(dvar[a], hours_req[h][a])
    for s in range(len(product)):
        constr[h].SetCoefficient(dvar[s], hours_req[h][s])

sales_constr = list(range(len(product)))
for s in range(len(product)):
    constr[s] = mymodel.Constraint(0, max_sales[s])
    for c in range(len(department)):
        constr[s].SetCoefficient(dvar[c], max_sales[s][c])
    for d in range(len(department)):
        constr[s].SetCoefficient(dvar[d], max_sales[s][d])
    for t in range(len(department)):
        constr[s].SetCoefficient(dvar[t], max_sales[s][t])
```

All of the code above works fine, until I get to the second constraint (sales_constr). At which point, I am given the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-116-a5209111faaa> in <module>
     14     constr[s] = mymodel.Constraint(0, max_sales[s])
     15     for c in range(len(department)):
---> 16         constr[s].SetCoefficient(dvar[c], max_sales[s][c])
     17     for d in range(len(department)):
     18         constr[s].SetCoefficient(dvar[d], max_sales[s][d])

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting this message? I've been trying to figure this out for way too long and I'm completely stumped - so any help would be very appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the position of list here `constr[s].SetCoefficient(dvar[d], max_sales[s][d])` wich is a `int` variable and trying to call method `SetCoefficient`.

You should make a instance of the class which SetCoefficient belongs or inherited then call the method, something like this:

```
...
it = MyClass()
it.SetCoefficient(x, y)
...
```

I don't know what you're using but i search for the method and found it [here](https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/python). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
max_sales = [360, 300, 100]
```

**max_sales** is an array of integers, but on line 16 you use two indices:

```
         constr[s].SetCoefficient(dvar[c], max_sales[s][c])
```

which means ***you're treating an integer as an array***.